# A free boolean algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Consider the following definition:

The boolean algebra $A$ is *generated freely* with the subset $G \subseteq A$ if for every boolean algebra $B$ and map $f:G \mapsto B$ there is precisely one homomorphism $\overline{f}:A \mapsto B$ extending $f.$ That is $\overline{f}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in G.$

I would like to check if $A = P(\mathbb{N})$ is generated freely by some subset $G.$

Clearly if $G$ generates $A$ then $G$ is not the empty set and it does not contain 0 or 1. Define a mapping $f$ such that a fixed $x  \in G$ is mapped to an atom if $x$ is not an atom, and to a non atom element otherwise.

Since any automorphism preserves atoms there is no way to extedn $f$ to a homomorphism from $A$ to $A$.

The above reasoning (if correct) would therefore imply that $A$ is not generated freely.

Am I mistaken?

Comment: What if $G$ itself has no atoms at all?

Comment: I've edited the answer. G clearly has some element. If $G$ has no atoms at all then take any element and construct a map taking the element to an atom.

Comment: I'm quite sure $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is a free boolean algebra for any _finite_ set $X$. Where have you used the infiniteness of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Suppose $\{x\},\{x,y\}\in G$. Then you send $\{x,y\}$ to some atom and $\{x\}$ to a whole other set, this would not preserve the fact that $\{x\}\cap\{x,y\}=\{x\}\implies f(\{x\})\cap f(\{x,y\})=f(\{x\})$. Your new map cannot be extended to a homomorphism, at all.

Comment: @Zhen Lin According to wikipedia every free bolean algbebra has $2^{2^n}$ elements which would imply that $P(X)$ is not always free even for finite $X$? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Azoo: Sorry, yes, I meant $\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(X))$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed $P(\mathbb{N})$ is not free. All infinite freely generated Boolean algebras are atomless, while $A$ is atomic. Furthermore, only the Boolean algebras that are generated by a finite set $G$ are finite (with $2^{2^{|G|}}$ many elements -if I'm not mistaken).

To see that if $G$ is infinite then $A$ is, is trivial. To see that if $G$ is finite then $A$ is finite you just need to check that $A$ is the Lindenbaum algebra of propositional logic with $|G|$ many atoms (check that this algebra satisfies the requirements).

To see that if $G$ is infinite then $A$ is atomless you do the following: Take an atomless Boolean algebra $B$ with $|G|$ many elements and define a mapping $f:G\to B$ such that $f[G]$ is dense, i.e. for every element  $b\in B$ there is some element in $c\in f[G]$ such that $c\leq b$. Then take the homomorphism $\bar{f}$ that extends $f$. If $A$ has an atom $a$, take $f(a)$, since $B$ is atomless, there is some $d<f(a)$ and there is some $c\in G$ such that $f(c)\leq d$. Then $0<f(a)\land f(c)<f(a)$ while $f(a\land c)$ is either $0$ or $f(a)$.

Actually you can completely describe what the freely generated Boolean algebra looks like, though it's a bit troublesome. You can find this is, for example, in Jonhstone's "*Stone Spaces*" (at the very end of the first chapter). The basic idea behind the construction lies in the fact that all propositions can be written in disjunctive normal form.

P.S.: I don't think your argument is correct, because you didn't seem to use the infiniteness of $\omega$ and as I have argued there are atomic freely generated Boolean algebras.

EDIT: The problem with your argument is that you assume that $\bar{f}$ will be an automorphism but this may not be the case. All that is required is that $\bar{f}$ is a homomorphism, which doesn't need to preserve atoms.

Comment: Just a small question. Why is there always an atomless boolean algebra of given cardinality |G|

Comment: @Azoo: That's a simple Lowenheim-Skolem argument. We know there is one atomless Boolean algebra. By the upwards and downwards Lowenheim-Skolem theorems we can find such an algebra of any size. Actually the unique (up to isomorphism) atomless Boolean algebra of countable size is the free algebra generated by a countable set.